# How to pass a string pointer-to-pointer from C to Python?

Tags: python, c, pointers, ctypes

I need to pass a string pointer-to-pointer from C to Python, so Python can update the pointer and C can read it later.

**Steps**

1. C set a `char**`
2. C call Python
3. Python allocate memory
4. Python update the `char**`
5. C read the string

**C Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef void (*CALLBACK)(char**);

CALLBACK g_cb;

// Expose API to register the callback
API void set_callback(CALLBACK cb) {
    g_cb = cb;
}

// Expose API to call the Python callback with a char**
API void call_python_function(char** pp) {
    if(g_cb) {
        g_cb(pp);
        printf("Python response: %s\n", *pp);
    }
}
```

**Python Code:**

```
import ctypes as ct

CALLBACK = ct.CFUNCTYPE(None, PPCHAR)

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.set_callback.argtypes = CALLBACK,
dll.set_callback.restype = None
dll.call_python_function.argtypes = POINTER(POINTER(ctypes.c_char)),
dll.call_python_function.restype = None
dll.set_callback(my_function)

def my_function(pp):
    buffer = ct.create_string_buffer(128)
    pp = buffer
```

**Output:**

```
Python response: (null)
```

No errors or warnings while building, C can call the Python function no issue, but Python can't update the `char**`. My question is **How can I pass a string pointer-to-pointer from C to Python ?**

Comment: Have you considered providing a function written in C that takes a Python string and performs the update, and calling that function from your Python code?

Comment: Please show *call\_python\_function* code.

Comment: I want to avoid extra non-necessary code to avoid XY problems, but I can guarantee that the hidden code has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: What's *c\_dll*? [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Anyone familiar with `ctypes` will know the DLL calls, sorry, but I want to keep the question short to avoid the XY problem.

Comment: It's still a good idea to make a working example of the problem, so each person answering doesn't have to write that C code for testing.  Then the answerer can focus on just the answer and not building a test case.

Comment: I got it, thank you for explaining this point.

Comment: I edited the question, now it's a working example, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example of passing a `char**` from C to Python.

**test.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef void (*CALLBACK)(char**);

CALLBACK g_cb;

// Expose API to register the callback
API void set_callback(CALLBACK cb) {
    g_cb = cb;
}

// Expose API to call the Python callback with a char**
API void call_python_function(char** pp) {
    if(g_cb) {
        g_cb(pp);
        printf("%s\n", *pp);
    }
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

# Set up some types.
# Note that `c_char_p` can't be used as ctypes has special handling
# to convert it to a Python bytes object that inteferes with the
# callback working properly.
PCHAR = ct.POINTER(ct.c_char)
PPCHAR = ct.POINTER(PCHAR)
CALLBACK = ct.CFUNCTYPE(None, PPCHAR) # Note first parameter is return value

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
# Declare function arguments and return values
dll.set_callback.argtypes = CALLBACK,
dll.set_callback.restype = None
dll.call_python_function.argtypes = PPCHAR,
dll.call_python_function.restype = None

# Set up callback function.  Note that the buffer can't go out-of-scope
# once the function returns or undefined behavior occurs, so the buffer
# is stored as an attribute of the function object so it will continue
# to exist.  A global variable would work, too.
@CALLBACK
def my_function(pp):
    my_function.buffer = ct.create_string_buffer(b'Hi From Python')
    pp[0] = my_function.buffer  # [0] dereferences char** so can assign char*

dll.set_callback(my_function)
p = PCHAR()
dll.call_python_function(ct.byref(p))
# Cast to a `c_char_p` to access `.value` and get a bytes object
# up to the terminating null.
print(ct.cast(p, ct.c_char_p).value)
```

Output:

```
Hi From Python
b'Hi From Python'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, the `PPCHAR` idea did the trick, Thank you for your answer, and thank you for your good explanations in the comments.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and add a comment `# my_function.buffer does not need to be freed`? I will appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: @AlbertShown If you want to free the memory, you'd need an explicit `del my_function.buffer`.  I was just pointing out that it will be freed automatically if it was just used as a local variable and it needs to be stored in the function object or a global variable somewhere.  It's up to you if and when you want to free it in your application.  It may also appear to work even as a local variable, but I proved to myself it was freed by using a debug Python build where a freed buffer is filled with a byte pattern and it is definitely freed.

Comment: Awesome, so no need to worry about it.

Comment: Basically after `printf("%s\n", *pp);` I don't need `my_function.buffer` anymore, so I was worried if calling the function will create a new instance & new buffer every time without freeing it (memory leak).